# JS function won't hide element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to hide or show a div when clicking on a link.

**This is the HTML part that I want to show or hide:**

```
<div id="product">
    <div ng-repeat="producto in productos" >     
            <figure class="floating">
              <img  ng-src="{{ producto.image }}" alt="image" class="rcorners3" style='width:100%;' border="0" alt="Null">
              <figcaption> {{ producto.name }}</figcaption>
            </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

**When clicking this:**

```
<li onclick="isitvisible()" class="guides">
```

**And this is the script I run when clicking:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isitvisible() {
        var vale = document.getElementById('product').offsetLeft;

        if (vale <= 0) {
            document.getElementById('product').style.visibility='hidden';
        } else { 
            document.getElementById('product').style.visibility='visible';
        }       
    }         
</script>
```

The div would hide but not show at all after clicking. I think I'm failing with the offsetLeft but not sure.

Comment: vale is always the same value. You're always hiding the element but never showing it.

Comment: If you add a `console.log(vale)` right after getting it, what do you see?

Comment: Why are you not using the angular way?

Comment: Yeah, I added an alert and it always was 0, that means that vale never changed value. You're all right. @rolodex I'm not sure what you mean by the "angular way" .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`offsetLeft` doesn't change when you toggle a element's visibility.

Try this `isitvisible`  function instead:

```
function isitvisible() {
    // Get a reference to the element's style.
    var style = document.getElementById('product').style;

    if (style.visibility === 'hidden') {
        style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else { 
        style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }       
}
```

Or a little [shorter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
function isitvisible() {
    var style = document.getElementById('product').style;
    style.visibility = (style.visibility === 'hidden') ? 'visible' : 'hidden';       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I'm new to JS and don't know lot of syntax.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for accepting my answer! You'll learn more in time.

Comment: Yes, I will, not worried about it, always did more oriented desktop stuff and now that I'm getting more into web/apps it's like I'm coming from the prehistory. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var style = document.getElementById('product').style;
    function isitvisible() {
        if (style.display=='none') {
            style.display='block';
        } else { 
            style.display='none';
        }       
    }         
</script>
```